# Make radio button and label in same line and when label text is big wrap in multiplelines

Tags: html, css

I want my radio button and its label to be on same line. I am able to achieve it. But when right side label is big it needs to wrap in a specific format. How do i achieve it. I can achieve using widths, any other option available?

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<input type='radio'>
<label class='label'>This is a very big text and should wrap as attached in image</label>
```

[image]

Comment: Provide your CSS as well.

Comment: You could `float` the radio button `left` and declare a `margin-bottom` property value great enough to disallow any text wrapping directly beneath it.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError - How much margin bottom can i give. Some times the text may be less also

Comment: What is your actual need keep the radio center in left followed by multiple text lines, suppose you have 10 lines of text then label should position in number 5 line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to add `display:flex` to wrapper:

```css
.wrapper {
 display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
<input type='radio'>
<label class='label'>This is a very big text and should wrap as attached in image text and should wrap as attached in imag</label>
</div>
```

Also easy if you need some alignment:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin:20px 0;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper' >
  <input type='radio'>
  <label class='label'>This is a very big text and should wrap as attached in image text and should wrap as attached in imag text and should wrap as attached in image text and should wrap as attached in imag text and should wrap as attached in image text and should wrap as attached in imag</label>
</div>
<div class='wrapper' style="align-items:center;">
  <input type='radio'>
  <label class='label'>This is a very big text and should wrap as attached in image text and should wrap as attached in imag text and should wrap as attached in image text and should wrap as attached in imag text and should wrap as attached in image text and should wrap as attached in imag</label>
</div>
<div class='wrapper' style="align-items:flex-end;">
  <input type='radio'>
  <label class='label'>This is a very big text and should wrap as attached in image text and should wrap as attached in imag text and should wrap as attached in image text and should wrap as attached in imag text and should wrap as attached in image text and should wrap as attached in imag</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could align radio button to left and text to right using the CSS property `float` to achievement the requirement as follows. [Working example](https://codepen.io/Kartm/pen/wprxYO).

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<input type='radio'>
<label class='label'>This is a very big text and should wrap as attached in image</label>
</div>

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}
.wrapper input {
  float :left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5%;
}
.wrapper label {
  float:right;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 91%;
}
```